# View's android:onClick as static method, possible?

Tags: java, android

As documentation says

> Name of the method in this View's context to invoke when the view is clicked.

Perfect, but is it "somehow" possible to create a static method and use it everywhere I need, not to define inside each `Activity` class. And yes I'm aware of defining the method inside base Activity class. All I'm looking for is to just write full name of method and let it uses it. Possible ?

Thanks

Comment: use `getActivity()` for call static methods in Activity

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a static method to the onClick xml property. You'll have to add the method you specify there to any activity that consumes the layout. You can have that method in each activity call a static method that actually handles the click, but there's no way to avoid having the instance methods altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Android searches for this method in an activity instance. That is why it must belong to an instance.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is you create a class that handles all the functions that the buttons does
and call that function on the Activity's onClick method.

Example

```
public class AppModel {

    public static void button1Function(){
        //do something
    }
}
```

then on your activities

```
 public void button1Clicked(View view){
     AppModel.button1Function();
 }
```

I think this looks like the MVC design paradigm. Click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create an entire new class having your static method?

You can load this class wherever you want then...